# Creating a linked list from scratch in java but remove method isn't working

Tags: java, linked-list

Creating a linked list but have become stumped at my remove method. My list contains:

```
Node<String> text1 = new Node<>();
text1.setData("Hello");
Node<String> text2 = new Node<>();
text2.setData("World");
Node<String> text3 = new Node<>();
text3.setData("Test");
```

having the list be removed would be:

```
card.remove(text1);
```

Once executed, the method should display true after a message prompting that the node has indeed been removed however, the method would never reach within the while statement and go straight to returning it to false.

I know the problem is my while statement but I have tried changing it numerous times to:

```
while (current != null) 
while (current != node) 
while (current.getNext() != null || current == tail)
while (current != null && current.getNext != node)
```

etc.

It would either return false or just show a NullPointerException Error

```
public boolean remove(Node node) {
    if (listSize == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("nothing to delete here :/");
    }
    boolean result = false;
    Node prev = head;
    Node current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        if (node.equals(current.getData())) {
            if (listSize == 1) {
                head = null;
                tail = null;
            } else if (current.equals(head)) {
                head = head.getNext();
            } else if (current.equals(tail)) {
                tail = prev;
                tail.setNext(null);
            } else {
                prev.setNext(current.getNext());
            }
            current.setNext(current.getNext());
            listSize--;
            result = true;
        }
        prev = current;
        current = prev.getNext();
    }
    return result;
}
```

The expected output should look like something like this after the method runs smoothly

```
removed text 3: true (removed)
```

right now it shows:

```
remove text 3: false (removed)
```

Comment: node.equals(current.getData()) looks like you're comparing a node to data

Comment: okay I have removed the if statement you pointed to and the method worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `node` is a `Node` object but you are comparing it with a String object. Try
`node.getData().equals(current.getData())` in stead of `node.equals(current.getData())` for comparing.